# Regex to find static (non final) variables

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I am trying to do a search in my Eclipse (Java) workspace to find all instances of static variables that are not final.

I tried various regexes but they do not result in any matches. Can someone suggest a regex that will match all lines containing `static` and not containing `final`, and not ending in a `{`?

The last part about not ending with a `{` will eliminate static methods.

An example:

```
public class FlagOffendingStatics {
  private static String shouldBeFlagged = "not ok";
  private static final String ok = "this is fine";
  public static void methodsAreOK() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This pattern works:

```
[^(final)] static [^(final)][^(\})]*$
```

Here is a test:

```
$ cat test.txt
private int x = "3";
private static x = "3";
private final static String x = "3";
private static final String x = "3";
private static String x = "3";
public static void main(String args[]) {
        blah;
}

$ grep "[^(final)] static [^(final)][^(\})]*$" test.txt
private static x = "3";
private static String x = "3";
```

(I realize that `private static x = "3";` isn't valid syntax, but the pattern still holds ok.)

The pattern accounts for the fact that `final` can appear before or after `static` with `[^(final)] static [^(final)]`. The rest of the pattern, `[^(\})]*$`, is meant to prevent any `{` characters from appearing in the remainder of the line.

This pattern will not work however if anyone likes to write their method statements like this:

```
private static void blah()
{
     //hi!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking for the absence of a brace, I would look for a semicolon at the end:

```
^(?![ \t]*import\b)(?!.*\bfinal\b).*\bstatic\b.*;[ \t]*$
```

Comment: This also matches static imports.

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, static imports didn't exist when this answer was written; fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse should have some sort of Java search built-in where you could specify that... Else, instead of writing one large monster regexp, try chaining together a bunch of greps:

`grep -r static . | grep -v final`

in the 1st statement, the -r causes the grep to recurse over a directory tree starting at the local directory, the results get piped to the 2nd grep which removes all the 
`final`'s. Keep adding -v until everything superfluous is removed from the results. This is usually easier --albeit less elegant-- than figuring out a complicated regexp to take care of everything.

Comment: Yes this too might work, however I was not able to chain searches from Eclipse.

Maybe I can try running this from a CygWin command prompt.

--
Thanks
Parag

Comment: -1 because console tools are great, but the integrated solutions are the requested answers here.

Answer (score 3):

Improved pattern from @matt-b

```
[^(final|import)] static [^(final|class|{|enum)][^(\})]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) will find static non-final variables for you. (Along with many other interesting things.) I've had good results with using the standalone version. There is also an Eclipse plugin, but I haven't used that.

Comment: Yes FindBugs is a very good tool. I use it's Eclipse plugin, but it does not detect all instances of (non final) static attributes.

More details in your edited comment...

Comment: Hmmm, I guess answers cannot be edited. FindBugs does not flag static attributes in static inner classes.

Comment: Also sometimes FindBugs does not report all static attributes in a class. I have a class with the following static attributes:
public static int READ_ONLY = 0;
public static int READ = 1;
public static int WRITE = 2;
FindBugs reported only the second and third attributes and not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the IntelliJ code inspections already does this. You can actually run the code inspector stand alone if you want and have it generate a report (usefull for a nightly build).

As the previous poster said, Find Bugs will do this and I imagine other code inspection tools will do it as well. You're probably better off integrating one of those more complete code inspection tools rather than a one-off script just for this one thing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a regex, but here is a plugin called checkstyle that will do that for you, as well as many other source checks. It even fixes many problems it finds automatically.

http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update/