# Searching For Non Final Static Variables in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I am programming in Java in Eclipse. I was wondering if there is a way to search for all non final static variables in my code base.

For example:

```
private static int MY_VAR = 0;
```

But not:

```
public static final int MY_CONSTANT = 1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240648/regex-to-find-static-non-final-variables), a regex could do the job.

I would however prefer [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) for a more complete detection
(or at least use the regex in a [checkstyle configuration](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html))

Those static analysis tools can generate much more useful informations than just list non-final static variables, as they detect when and describe why a given practice is inappropriate.